# Modifying HM inter prediction to use original blocks as references

Tags: hevc

How can I modify the estIntraPredLumaQT function or other code in the inter frame prediction part of HM to use the original blocks instead of reconstructed blocks as reference when performing inter frame prediction with different QPs, so that it becomes more like lossless inter frame prediction?

I want to modify the lossy intra frame prediction in HM to be lossless. As a first step, I think I need to replace the reconstructed reference blocks it uses with the original blocks.